# truetext/false text property not changing value in output in react

Tags: devextreme

I have a column in react devextreme datagrid:

```
<Column
  dataType="Boolean"
  dataField="noFollow"
  filterType="exclude"
  caption="NoFollow"
  allowFiltering={false}
  allowHeaderFiltering={true}
  trueText="[x]"
  falseText="[ ]"
  showEditorAlways={false}
>
  <HeaderFilter dataSource={WatchedUrlGrid.noFollowFilterTypes} />
</Column>
```

But the `trueText` and `falseText` values are not being used.  It just outputs `true` or `false` and no errors present.

What is wrong with column definition?

Answer (score 0):

try with

```
dataType="boolean"
```

[image]